# Create Dynamic Content record with API results in system_parent_id = null

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-dynamic-content-types

I'm desperate for an answer to this. I'm using the Sitefinity API to create Child Items for a Parent Item. (These are dynamic content types in a dynamic module)

At the end of setting the properties I do the following:

```
historicDataEntry.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");
dynamicModuleManager.Lifecycle.Publish(historicDataEntry);
historicDataEntry.SetParent(GetFundIDToUse(), etfType.FullName);
dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges();
```

The result is two records in the sf_dynamic_content table which is right, but the second record for some reason has a system_parent_id of null even though it gets the values visible = 1 and status = 2.

It's as though I'm missing something in the process because when the Live record is created it's not copying the parent_id even though the Master record correctly references the Parent ID.

If I go into the admin interface, open the record I created and click publish THEN it copies the parent ID correctly, but the API approach doesn't do that. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely set the parent before calling Publish and before setting the workflow status.

Here is a sample code:

```
var parentMasterId = Id_of_the_parent_item;

// type is the full name of the dynamic module
string resolvedType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType(type);

// create the child item
var itemToCreate = manager.CreateDataItem(resolvedType);

// set some other properties of the child, like Title, etc.

// set the parent of the child
itemToCreate.SetParent(parentMasterId, "full_name_of_the_parent_type");

itemToCreate.SetWorkflowStatus(manager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");

manager.Lifecycle.Publish(itemToCreate);

manager.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yip I that's the answer. I figured it out just before getting your response. The strange thing is that in the code reference provided by the Module Builder does it the other way around.